# Use select count in CRM dynamics SDK.Query.QueryExpression

Tags: c#, sql, dynamics-crm

Using c#, I need to build a query using the SDK.Query.QueryExpression library for Microsoft Dynamics 2015. I am unable to figure out how to order and count the number of occurrences.

I want to get a count of how many times each Product was used in all the Opportunities.

The sql query itself is rather simple:

```
SELECT b.Name, count(a.ProductId) as 'accurances'
FROM [ProkonCRM_MSCRM].[dbo].[OpportunityProductBase] a,
     [ProkonCRM_MSCRM].[dbo].[ProductBase] b
where a.ProductId = b.ProductId
group by b.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you have an on-premise implementation of CRM 2015. 
Based on that assumption, you have the option to query your CRM database directly and perform your SQL query using C# (e.g. using the Microsoft.Data.SQL library).

It is important that you query the **FilteredViews** as this is the recommended way to directly query the CRM database.

**FilteredViews** Reference: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531182.aspx

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know aggregate functions are not supported with QueryExpressions. 
You might want to look at FetchXML for this, as aggregate functions are supported there.
Here are some samples for using FetchXML to achieve what you want:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309565.aspx#count

Example in FetchXML (not tested, your entity names may differ, I assumed it's an N:N relationship)

```
<fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical' aggregate='true'> 
    <entity name='product'> 
       <attribute name='name' alias='productName' groupby='true'/> 
       <link-entity name='opportunityproduct' from='opportunityid' to='opportunityid'>
           <attribute name='productid' alias='occurences' aggregate='count' />
       </link-entity> 
    </entity> 
</fetch>
```